# Why is a dash displayed as a dash on Android, but displayed as an underscore on iOS in my Flutter mobile app?

Tags: flutter, dart

My flutter app displays a `-` (dash) between two times.

`5:30pm - 11:00pm`

On Android, this displays correctly, but on iOS the dash displays as an underscore.

`5:30pm _ 11:00pm`

Can anyone tell me why this is and how to correct it?

```
children: <Widget>[
  Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
        flex: 51,
        child: Text(
          data[i].jobName!,
          style: TextStyle(color: kBodyText, fontSize: 16),
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        flex: 23,
        child: Text(
          formatJsonTime24To12(data[i].startTime!)!
              .toLowerCase(),
          style: TextStyle(color: kBodyText, fontSize: 16),
          textAlign: TextAlign.right,
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        flex: 3,
        child: Text(
          ' -',
          style: TextStyle(color: kBodyText, fontSize: 16),
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        flex: 23,
        child: Text(
          formatJsonTime24To12(data[i].finishTime!)!
              .toLowerCase(),
          style: TextStyle(color: kBodyText, fontSize: 16),
          textAlign: TextAlign.right,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the ideas. Turns out it was the flex values I was using. The flex value of 3 was enough on the android emulator I was using. But on the iOS simulator (iPhone 12 Pro Max), this wasn't enough and the text was word wrapping and creating a second line. The dash was on the second line. I increased the 3 to 5 and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

In your TextField, just set the following code:

```
keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
inputFormatters: [WhitelistingTextInputFormatter(new RegExp('[ -]'))],
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely that in both cases the dash is actually display, but vertical alignment causes it to look like an underscore.

Since you are using a [Row](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Row-class.html), you should try adding `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.baseline` to all of its children.

This will tell `Row` to vertically align its children at their text baselines.